# SUMPRODUCT formula not working to highlight duplicates in one column, but not another?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sumproduct formula to show when an employee appears duplicate in column B, but column M value is different. It doesn't appear to be working, any ideas?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B=B1),--(M:M<>M1))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm confused by the question, so what is the output like? and do you mean that the sumproduct formula will count the same names in column "B"?

Comment: @Sunny so you see how Tom Smith is a duplicate value in column B, but has a different value in column M (Workday and then Bamboo). How do I populate a 1 in column N in this instance?

Comment: You have to start with B2 and M2 in the equations to leave out the header row

Comment: Your formula should be looking at row 1462 not 1461.

Comment: Also, it LOOKS like you just added a filter, so it may make sense to put your data in a table.  Then you don't have to do B:B or M:M but can just do the Column for the table

Comment: If you only want to validate whether it's a duplicate in column B, use the formula `=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B=B1462))`. Otherwise the data is not duplicated because of column M making it another unique record.